# How would I store and evaluate the user input from my calculator app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

Good morning!

I am still working on my calculator app and I'm trying to create a function that will store the input from the user and evaluate it. I don't know if this idea will work as intended, but I'm trying my best to keep from copying a tutorial and learn to think like a programmer.

```js
let reset = document.getElementById("reset"),
    output = document.getElementById("output"),
    calcButtons = document.getElementById("calc_buttons");
    
    
// Clears the calculator display
function clearScreen() {
  output.innerHTML = " "
}

// Keeps track of any of the calculator buttons being pressed
calcButtons.addEventListener("click", printNum, false);

// Prints the clicked buttons to the display allows them to concatenate 
function printNum(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    let clickedItem = e.target.value;
    output.innerHTML += clickedItem;
  };
};


function equal() {
  let userInput = document.getElementById("output").value;
  eval(userInput);
  console.log(eval(userInput));
}
```

```css
* {
  background-color: silver;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;  
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#calc_buttons {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 50vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6);
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#reset {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

#calc_buttons > button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #6699cc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}

#calc_buttons > button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(102, 153, 204, 70%);
}

#output {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  grid-column: span 4;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#calculator {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: silver;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 10px; 
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<HTML> 
  <h1> My First JavaScript Calculator </h2>
  <div id="calculator">
    
  <div id="calc_buttons">
    <span id="output"></span>
    
    <button onclick="clearScreen()"class="operate" id="reset">C</button>
    
    <button class="num" id="seven" value="7">7</button>
    <button class="num" id="eight" value="8">8</button>
    <button class="num" id="nine" value="9">9</button>
    
    <button class="operate" id="divide" value="/">/</button>
    
    
    <button class="num" id="four" value="4">4</button>
    <button class="num" id="five" value="5">5</button>
    <button class="num" id="six" value="6">6</button>
    
    <button class="operate" id="multiply" value="*">*</button>
    
    <button class="num" id="one" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="num" id="two" value="2">2</button>
    <button class="num" id="three" value="3">3</button>
  
    <button class="operate" id="minus" value="-">-</button>
    
  
    <button class="num" id="zero" value="0">0</button>
    
   <button class="operate" id="decimal" value=".">.</button>
   <button onclick="equal()" class="operate" id="equals" value="=">=</button>
   
   
   <button class="operate" id="plus" value="+">+</button>
   
</div>



</HTML>
```

https://codepen.io/tphelps5/pen/GRgBMMZ?editors=1010

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Add to the function equal `output.innerHTML = result;` that will print result on "screen", do you have db for store value or just for session?

Comment: Just for session